# How can I migrate mail from Entourage to Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, migration, entourage

I have an Entourage POP3 account. My e-mail and folders are stored locally on my Mac. I'm trying to migrate them to Outlook 2007. I have tried to export through Entourage, but it doesn't work. What can I do?